Is there a standardized process for Inductor selection calculation for boost LED controllers?
Through numerous datasheets that I've gone through in selecting an LED controller to use, I've come across two different methods that are used to estimate the needed inductance:

Based on the ripple current

Based on meeting the CCM-DCM boundary power requirement
 or 

Each brings about different estimations. For example, I am currently designing an LED boost controller that is compliant over three LED strings:
White - 1A @ 18V
Red - 1.5A @ 16.2V
Green - 1.5A @ 18.6V
V(IN_MIN) = 6V
V(IN_TYP) = 7.4V
V(IN_MAX) = 8.4V
fsw = 2.2MHz
Dmax = 0.71
I(L) = Iled/Dmax
= 1.5/(1-Dmax)
= 5.17A
If I assume an inductor ripple ratio of 10% => 0.1*5.17 = 0.517A
Using equation 1
L = (6x0.71)/(0.517x2.2x10^6) => 3.74uH
If I calculated it based on a 7% inductor ripple:
Inductor ripple = 0.07*5.17 = 0.3619
L = 5.2uH
Using equation 2
Po(BDRY) is usually taken as 1/3 of max Power => 1/3 * 18.6*1.5 = 9.3W
Using RHS equation
L = 1uH
Both are VERY different!!
When do you pick one method over another, and why???
After all that, understanding that increasing inductor size will have to be met with an increase in output capacitance to maintain stability. This is due to the unavoidable "right half plane zero" effect for the boost converter topology. Right half plane zero has the undesirable effect of increasing gain while decreasing phase. This requires that the loop gain be rolled off before this significantly affects the total loop response. This can be accomplished by reducing inductance (increasing RHPZ frequency) or increasing the output capacitor value (decreasing the loop gain). Once again, we must calculate the RHPZ frequency, phase and gain response, and adjust values accordingly to get a satisfactory inductor value.

What controller(s) are you looking at? What calculations do they give?  What type are they? (Peak current mode control for example requires less than a maximum inductance value.)

@TimWilliams Those formulas were from TPS92691, TPS92692, MAX25611B. They are constant-frequency, current mode controllers. Can you explain in more detail about "Peak current mode control for example requires less than a maximum inductance value"

These are both peak current mode controllers.
Peak current mode control is distinguished by having inherent instability, in CCM, for boost ratio >1:1 (or buck ratio >1:2, etc.).  We use slope compensation to assist with this, but it's more of a stopgap solution, or hack, and comes with downsides (looser current regulation: more dependent on Vin, Vout).
We generally plan for DCM (mainly when power levels are low[1] so the relatively poor efficiency, or relatively large components required to compensate, aren't a concern), or CCM with a high ripple fraction, say above 30%.  This is especially important when slope compensation is used.
The high ripple fraction generally dictates ferrite-core inductors, though many modern composite core materials are acceptable, again, especially at smaller power levels.
The MAX25611B instructions are not very good, I think.  They give various relations, but not how to connect them together, or illustrations of what they're all describing (e.g. waveforms at Vin min/max, nominal operation, current limiting, startup/fault).  Which makes it rather scattered to use.  A veteran will recognize the relations, and know when to apply them, but omitting such instruction leaves the novice behind.
I would suggest making a spreadsheet of all the equations, with limits as described in the text, and see if several relations have another limit which restricts the quoted relations.  Furthermore, plot the basic waveforms and understand where the basic voltage, current and inductance proportions arise from.  You won't be able to see, so easily, the importance of slope compensation, just from poking at spreadsheets, but setting up a low-power toy demo -- say with a simpler, traditional controller like UC3843 -- will show off many failure mechanisms at once, while being easy enough to breadboard and iterate quickly on.
TPS92691 suggests several ways, and you've merely picked one of them, I guess, arbitrarily.  They explain the condition:

As an alternative, the inductor can be selected based on CCM-DCM boundary condition specified based on output power, PO(BDRY). The choice of inductor ensures CCM operation in battery-powered LED driver applications that are designed to support different LED string configurations with a wide range of programmable LED current setpoints. The output power should be calculated based on the lowest LED current and the lowest output voltage requirements for a given application.

In other words, they suggest to plan for the worst case (min Vin, max Vout, min Iout) and achieve BCM there, ensuring CCM over the full operating area.  Given the stability hazard outlined above, this seems an irresponsible suggestion without also addressing those concerns.
They do mention slope compensation, but they don't seem to explain how/why/when to use it.  The above concerns show why this is problematic, and how to manage the hazard.
[1] To explain this a bit better: "Low" is relative; there isn't a hard threshold. It might be a few watts, where component size is already, say, 1206 chips or thereabouts, and using components of this size versus shrinking to 0805 or 0603.
Note that component size reduction might include choosing a more optimal/higher efficiency design, and maybe an enabling requirement is a better-performing regulator IC.  Perhaps that IC is more expensive than the difference for the components in the alternative solution.  Perhaps it takes more engineering effort to optimize the design to that point, and the production quantity simply isn't enough to justify that much work.  Etc.
The threshold could also be 100W or more; a typical offline 100W flyback power supply is DCM for example.  Practical alternatives for offline converters include forward (two-switch or half-bridge) and resonant (including QR flyback and full-wave LLC) types, which require more components, newer controllers, etc.  In production, it's a holistic compromise between all possible options, and these tend to be the conclusions -- but not because of any single reason.

This is as good an occasion as any to repeat:
As a general rule, appnotes are bad.
Appnotes are a terminal endpoint of information.  What they contain, has been condensed through various disparate channels (books, articles, word of mouth, coworkers), and lightly edited if at all.  They often aren't well written, they rarely cite sources, and they never derive or analyze a problem to show you how it works -- they are, after all, application notes, they should have complete solutions.  But often those solutions aren't complete, or they work only under assumptions that have been conveniently omitted through lazy writing and repetition; the professional equivalent of the telephone game.  Purple monkey boost converters.
Always read sources -- not just appnotes, they just happen to be a common trigger to wake up and notice these inconsistencies -- with a critical eye.  Cross-reference and check claims where possible.  Plot waveforms and equations, prove relationships.  Build your own independent understanding of how the system works; develop experiments to attempt to prove or disprove claims that you've derived from that understanding.  In short: apply the scientific method.  No, this isn't something we can afford to do on every project, but it's something that needs to be done, by the individual, at some point in ones' career (and preferably regularly, to reinforce and refresh that understanding), and is well worth setting aside the time, somehow, somewhere, to do it.

As a sort-of addendum to [1]: it's often the case that, in engineering, probably in the professions and sciences generally, or maybe even human habit most generally still -- when a reason isn't given, it's just kind of understood as a hand-wave over circumstances that simply aren't in question, aren't relevant to the topic at hand, or are obvious to those "skilled in the art".  (Well, for humans most generally, that will include the "if you don't know, I'm not going to tell you" sorts of mind-game behaviors some people pull.  I can't say such games will never be the case in the professions... but it is at least uncommon, and most people really do just want to represent and share their craft in good faith.)  So, suffice it to say, optimal choice of components in a converter, is a wildly complex topic -- involving real concerns of product manufacturing and sourcing, as well as technical concerns like characteristics and ratings -- each component adds several variables to the matrix -- so, you'll understand if I (and, most authors, for that matter) don't want to go into great detail about these things.

Just answered this at the same time I asked another question about slope compensation. This provides a solid framework to build up this knowledge. what are these "Always read sources" that you refer to? Yes, you are so true about these inconsistencies.

What are considered "lower power levels" to you. Many sources loosely mention low and high power, with no framework. So, you're saying in CCM it's better to design around a high ripple ratio than a lower one; that's a surprise. Why is that?

Sources; literature, documents.

Do you have any recommended literature, books to build up on that base knowledge.

"Low" is relative, so there isn't a hard threshold. It might be a few watts, where component size is already 1206 or thereabouts, and using components of this size versus shrinking to 0805 or 0603 (perhaps by choosing a more optimal/higher efficiency design) isn't worthwhile. Or it might be 100W or more; a typical offline 100W flyback power supply is DCM for example.

I don't have any particular references unfortunately, as I tend to read bits and pieces diversely and haven't kept notes on which ones have been influential to me. Also, given that scattered strategy, such a list might not be very useful to someone else, anyway -- or indeed the quality of those documents might not be good in general, as I drew a better conclusion together, than any one document, as a result of synthesizing multiple sources together.

That said, two random examples that come to mind: the old Unitrode (now TI) notes and books tend to be alright, and Fundamentals of Power Electronics, Maksimović & Erickson, is a tome I've seen widely cited.

Not a professional EE, just someone making a serious study of boost converters (and to a lesser extent, other kinds). So I may not be able to answer all of your questions. That said... I hope this is what you wanted.

The following Datasheet of an MC34063A contains a limited example of what you seek, a formula based approach for use with design of boost converters, including inductor sizing.
The following Digikey page contains a link to a datasheet containing the formulas. Multiple manufacturers make this chip, but some datasheets are better than others, so look over a few. I also like the Texas Instruments datasheet.
497-7849-2-ND at Digikey
STMicroelectronics
MC34063ABD-TR
Boost Formulas:

Notes covering formulas:


Watch the following video by Dave Jones of EEVBlog fame:
EEVblog #110 – Let’s Design a DC to DC Switchmode Converter

Above is a screenshot of the step-by-step treatment he gives a boost converter using an MC34063.

Make a couple converters using the formulaic approach you learned from the previous resources, then come back here again and ask any questions that you still have.
And do not neglect to read the latest Art of Electronics and realize that this discipline is engineering, art, and more.
